# Cannot find function in google docs file error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I know some JS and I have a fair amount of experience with VBA scripts for MSO, but I'm just starting to learn how to script google docs, and I'm having difficulty with the google scripting environment.

I created a doc on my google drive, and I am trying to log outputs in the code, but I get an error when I get the error *TypeError: Cannot find function getBody in object Excel Download Macro Log File. (line 56, file "Code")* when I try to run this code:

```
function logDataFromCode() {

  var LogDoc = DriveApp.getFilesByName('Excel Download Macro Log File').next();

  // Access the body of LogDoc, then add a paragraph with relevant data from script:
  LogDoc.getBody()
    .appendPageBreak()
    .appendParagraph("[put variables to log here]");
}
```

Can someone please explain why I am getting this error?

Comment: if you log `LogDoc`, what type of object is it?

Comment: is the doc you created on your drive a Google doc ? are you sure it is not a "normal" text file ? That would definitely explain the error message you get...

Comment: @Liora HaydontI don't see anything that looks like an object type method, so how would I actually check that?  I get null when I run `Logger.log(logDoc.getDescription());`.

Comment: Just run `Logger.log(logDoc)`

Comment: @Sergeinsas I'm pretty sure it's a google doc.  I can open and view the file from my drive with google docs.  The logging method worked the first time I tried it because I had the script generate the document, but started giving me errors when I tried to edit the existing file.

Comment: @LioraHaydont That just gives me the text *Excel Download Macro Log File*.

Comment: Have you tried to cast it? looks like `LogDoc` is a `file` and you want a `document`, try calling `((Document)LogDoc).getBody()`

Comment: @LioraHaydont `((Document)LogDoc).getBody()` gives me an error.  Is there something else I need to do for casting to work properly?  I don't really know much about casting in JS.

Comment: what error does it give you?

Comment: @LioraHaydont Hmm... weird.  It says *Missing ; before statement. (line 12, file "Code")*

Comment: The cast doesn't seem to work, humm. Try `var doc = DocumentApp.openById(LogDoc.getId()); doc.getBody()`?

Comment: @LioraHaydont Actually when I use your syntax it says *Missing ) in parenthetical. (line 12, file "Code")*.  The other error message I got because I was playing around with the syntax and forgot to change it back.

Comment: @LioraHaydont I get *ReferenceError: "LogDoc" is not defined. (line 10, file "Code")* on the line `var doc = DocumentApp.openById(LogDoc.getId()); `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166568/discussion-between-liora-haydont-and-nateatwork).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `LogDoc` is a `File`, but you want it to be a `Document`

The best way to cast it is to get it's id and then accesing it using the `DocumentApp` to open it.

Like this:

```
var LogFile = DriveApp.getFilesByName('Excel Download Macro Log File').next();
var LogDoc = DocumentApp.openById(LogFile.getId());
// Access the body of LogDoc, then add a paragraph with relevant data from script:
LogDoc.getBody()
```

Answer (score 3):

You are getting that error because the class returned by `getFilesByName("name").next()` is of type [`File`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file.html), not [`Document`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document).

The solution is to use the `File` from `DriveApp` to explicitly open a `Document` via `DocumentApp`:

```
var LogDoc, files = DriveApp.getFilesByName("the file name");
if(files.hasNext()) {
  LogDoc = DocumentApp.openById(files.next().getId());
} else {
  // No files matched the name supplied to DriveApp
  return;
}
```